# Deserialize incorrect string array?

Tags: deserialization

I am pulling a JSON formatted string from a database in some cases this string is just an array, but it badly formatted. I have no control over the data shape.

The string looks like this:

`"[Hello, World]"`

I want to parse this string to an array using JSON.parse, but that doesn't work when there are no quotes arround it.

So I need to somehow transform this string to this `["Hello", "World"]`

Comment: The main problem here is: are you certain that commas are a unambiguous delimeter? I mean, are you sure that the individual values themselves don't contain a comma ?

Comment: Save it in a way that it can be parsed as is like \"[\"Hello\", \"world\"]\"

Comment: @Pac0 that might also be possible, the data comes from DraftJS, so I don't know if there is any way to just convert from DraftJS

Comment: @Raghuveer I don't have control over the way the data is strored. That is another department

Comment: There no details in the question that would help us understand the context with draftJS, so currently I couldn't say if there is some "direct way".
And if the values may contain commas, or let's say "comma then space", then you have no easy way to ensure proper deserialization, the format is inherently ambiguous. What you can do is remove the brackets, and split the string on `, `, and hope the result array is correct.

Comment: @IAMTHEBEST you have to extract as a JSONArray and not as object. That should help you get going.

Comment: I see what the problem was it was implementation specific. Not relevant for SO. So this question will be closed.